# How to put a see through filter over an image with text above the filter

Tags: html, css, mousehover, onhover

essentially I am trying to recreate the hover over from this sight  when hovering over the squares. http://thehf.org/ can anyone enlighten me on how this is done?

Comment: to accept an answer, hover beside the answer in question and click the tick that appears beside it. It means 15 points for the answerer and you get a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Its done through [web-filters](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/), which are applied in your css. there are a variety available, sepia, invert, grayscale to name a few.

here's a full [code example](http://www.bootply.com/lgE3WwzWaC) with the `sepia` and `invert` demonstrated